# Why am I getting a fail to initialize 3d engine error upon launching Gratuitous Space Battles?

Tags: gratuitous-space-battles

Okay, first, the complete error message is: failed to initialize 3d engine: ... src/Game.cpp 343. I originally purchased this game when I had a different computer (which used Windows 7). I now have a new computer (which uses Windows 8) and the very first time I tried to play this game after installing it on my new computer, I got the error message mentioned above. I've tried reinstalling it, but to no avail.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based off of: https://positech.co.uk/forums/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=21&t=5723

This can be fixed by deleting the \Documents\My Games\GratuitousSpaceBattles folder, then restarting the game.

Comment: I felt the need to add this question and answer because it was really quite difficult to find this information via google search. Hopefully it will be more helpful now that it's in a less obscure place.